# How to position html objects on a portlet jsp?

Tags: html, css, jsp, position, portlet

I'm trying to position objects like `<button>` in a `.jsp` page via `css`.

**MyTheme.css:**

```
.btn {
position: relative;
top: 10px;
/* more css */
}
```

**The result:**[image: Positon: relativ; top: 10px;]

The problem i have is, that there is a scrollbar at the left side of the portlet, which is scrollable the `10px` from the `MyTheme.css` file, but i don't want that my portlet have a scrollbar. If i remove the `position: relativ;` the page looks like this:

[image: Without any position attribute]

This is a bit better cause there is no scrollbar, but as you can seen in the red box, the buttons have no space to the `<fieldset>`, which also looks bad.

**I tried:**

- Put a `<div>` around the code (nothing happend)
- `position: absolute` (like expected the button were somewhere on the site)
- `posotion: static`

**Want i want to achieve:**

Position `html` objects somewhere on the `.jsp` page without the scrollbar on the left or on the bottom.

I'm using the WebSphere Portal Server 8.5. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `margin-top` (on a div around the buttons) to move them without leaving their original space reserved.

```
div.btn-container {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```